# On leads and referrals if i need to add "Send list email" how do i add it?

Tags: leads, sales-cloud

I have checked the permission for my profile and i have permission to send bulk emails.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  YOur question needs more detail - please [edit] your post to include a screenshot of where you expect to see the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For send List of emails, you need to have **Allow sending of List Emails** System Permission in your profile.

Once you have this permission, You can able to view **Send List Email** button in your Lightning Experience List view page on Lead tab *[Note: Sometimes that button available in dropdown also].*

For further **Send List Emails** functions you can refer this [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_list_email_create.htm&type=5).

Thanks.

Comment: My profile has that permission but i still donot see the button .

Comment: @Tejashree Hi, Can you please help to check whether you're org's `Deliverability` (Go to Setup >> Deliverability) settings is set as **All Emails** instead of other options?